# Rotate View While Scrolling

Tags: objective-c, scroll, rotation

Pretty simple Question:

I have a ScrollView and an ImageView. For every pixel scrolled, the ImageView should rotate a certain amount of degrees.

Any ideas how to do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like you're new to Stack Overflow. When you have a satisfactory answer, make sure you click the check mark next to it to tag it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` and rotate with an affine transform.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    CGFloat rotateDegrees = offset.y;
    CGFloat rotateRadians = rotateDegrees * (M_PI / 180);
    _myImage.layer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotateRadians);
}
```

To reset the rotation, use `_myImage.layer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity`.

Comment: +10 awesome for you, sir! Thank you, exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Assign a [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate.html) for the scroll view and implement the `-scrollViewDidScroll:` method. This gets called every time the scroll view moves. In that method, get the `contentOffset` of the scroll view, and compare it to some saved initial state. That gets you the number of pixels/points scrolled.

Figure out how much you want to rotate the image as a result, and create a rotation transform with `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` ([docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformMakeRotation)), and assign it to the image view's `transform` property.

Answer (score 0):

Vertical scrolling and Swift 5:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let topOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let angle = -topOffset * 2 * CGFloat(Double.pi / 180)
    self.myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
}
```

And, yeah, don't forget to do this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.scrollView.delegate = self
```